# Numbered lists interspersed with commentary.

Tags: discussion, markdown

Sometimes I want to intersperse commentary into my lists. For example.

> Thus, it holds that
>
> 1. blah, and that
> 2. blurg,
>
> and noting that bloop, thus also that
>
> 1. blipple.

However, the numbering begins at $1$ again after the commentary. Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1571/264

Comment: @Zev I'm sorry - this is the second time today I've answered a question which you immediately pointed out was a duplicate.

Comment: @mixedmath, but you answer was really  good!!!

Comment: :-) I like especially the poetic climax up to the heavenly "blipple"...

Comment: In [meta.SO discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137077) someone quoted Markdown documentation: "At some point in the future, Markdown may support starting ordered lists at an arbitrary number." But so far, there is no way to change the numbering in a list without it no longer being a list. Even if one types in html tags for ordered list, the attributes `start` and `value` are not parsed.

Answer (score 2):

1. First item

   I'd like to say a few things about this - but it's not always easy. Let me skip my first point and go to my second point instead.
2. Ok, now we can go on.

   Actually, this is not so easy.

   Give me one more try. Hmm.... $$1 + 2 = 3$$

   Ah, that's right. I meant to go to -
3. My third item. Seems about right to me to end it here.

And I conclude my presentation.

---

Source:

```
1. First item

  I'd like to say a few things about this - but it's not always easy. Let me skip my first point and go to my second point instead.

2. Ok, now we can go on.

  Actually, this is not so easy.

  Give me one more try. Hmm.... $$1 + 2 = 3$$

  Ah, that's right. I meant to go to - 

3. My third item. Seems about right to me to end it here.

And I conclude my presentation.
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this is seen as a solution. In the problem-statement it seems, as if explicitely the comment before the last item was non-indented, so is ***not*** a part of the list or of one of its items. So we might say, it is an interspearsed ***meta-comment***. Only after that list-external comment the list gets continued with the next item-number. For me this is a -well, you might say, much sophisticated - difference of the function/appeal of that comment (which I would like to preserve anyway - for some possible application in my own answers...)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it's better to live with the limitations of Markdown than hack around them. But if you absolutely have to have a comment that's not indented as list items are, you can un-indent a **single** line of text using text-in-MathJax:

`$\hspace{-0.8cm}\text{and noting that bloop, thus also that}$`

1. blah, and that
2. blurg,
   $\hspace{-0.8cm}\text{and noting that bloop, thus also that}$
3. blipple.

Source (where I put `<br>` instead of two spaces, because spaces are not visible)

```
1. blah, and that
2. blurg,<br>
$\hspace{-0.8cm}\text{and noting that bloop, thus also that}$       
3. blipple.
```

Version with more vertical space:

1. blah, and that
2. blurg,
   $\hspace{-0.8cm}\text{and noting that bloop, thus also that}$
3. blipple.

Source:

```
1. blah, and that
2. blurg,<br><br>
$\hspace{-0.8cm}\text{and noting that bloop, thus also that}$       
3. blipple.
```

Comment: <ggg> This thread is beginning to call for nomination for the Dadaism-award...<blipple>...<blurg> (Is possibly an avatar of the venerable Don Martin (RiP!) around?)